# Msg 142, Level 15, State 2 -- Can't figure out what I have wrong

Tags: sql-server

I've looked at other threads for the error I'm receiving, but I don't see where I'm making the mistake and don't see any extra commas, which seems to be the main cause of issues. I'd be very appreciative if someone could point out where I'm making my error.

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts.AdminUsers ( admID             INT              NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1,1)
                          , admFN            VARCHAR(35)      NULL
                          , admLN            VARCHAR(35)      NULL
                          , admUserName  VARCHAR(64)      NOT NULL
                          , admPass      VARCHAR(128)     NOT NULL
                          , admPassIV        VARCHAR(32)      NOT NULL
                          , admPassResetDate DATETIME2    NULL
                          , admEEID      VARCHAR(30)      NULL
                          , admEmail         VARCHAR(255)     NULL
                          , admAcctEnabled   BIT              NOT NULL
                          , admHier      HIERARCHYID      NOT NULL
                          , admNumLogins     SMALLINT         NULL
                          , admLastLogin     DATETIME2    NULL
                          , admCreateTS  DATETIME2    NOT NULL
                          , admTID       TINYINT          NOT NULL
                          , CONSTRAINT PK_Accounts_AdminUsers
                            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (admID)
                          , CONSTRAINT DF_Accounts_AdminUsers_admAcctEnabled 
                            DEFAULT (1)
                          , CONSTRAINT DF_Accounts_AdminUsers_admCreateTS 
                            DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                          , CONSTRAINT FK_Accounts_AdminUsers_AdminUserTypes
                            FOREIGN KEY (admTID) REFERENCES Accounts.AdminUserTypes(admTID)
                          );
```

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: @scsimon Msg 142, Level 15, State 2, Line 25
Incorrect syntax for definition of the 'TABLE' constraint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Move the CONSTRAINT DEFAULT next to the field definition:

```
CREATE TABLE Accounts.AdminUsers ( admID             INT              NOT NULL    IDENTITY(1,1)
                          , admFN            VARCHAR(35)      NULL
                          , admLN            VARCHAR(35)      NULL
                          , admUserName  VARCHAR(64)      NOT NULL
                          , admPass      VARCHAR(128)     NOT NULL
                          , admPassIV        VARCHAR(32)      NOT NULL
                          , admPassResetDate DATETIME2    NULL
                          , admEEID      VARCHAR(30)      NULL
                          , admEmail         VARCHAR(255)     NULL
                          , admAcctEnabled   BIT              NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Accounts_AdminUsers_admAcctEnabled 
                            DEFAULT (1)
                          , admHier      HIERARCHYID      NOT NULL
                          , admNumLogins     SMALLINT         NULL
                          , admLastLogin     DATETIME2    NULL
                          , admCreateTS  DATETIME2    NOT NULL CONSTRAINT DF_Accounts_AdminUsers_admCreateTS 
                            DEFAULT (CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
                          , admTID       TINYINT          NOT NULL
                          , CONSTRAINT PK_Accounts_AdminUsers
                            PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED (admID)
                          );
```